# How to use filepond with Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, filepond

As the title suggest.

I have searched Google and stackoverflow, so far I don't find any tutorial that doesn't involve (https://github.com/ImperialCollegeLondon/django-drf-filepond).

While this library seems maintain, at 68 stars, too much risk and I prefer to do without it.

### What I tried

When you use filepond `input` tag with class `file-uploader file-uploader-grid`, in browser, it will compile and generate a `div` tag.

The issue is that the `id` in `input` will be generated under the `div` instead of `input` tag.

Without that `id`, when the form is submitted, `self.request.FILES` will be empty dictionary.

So I tried writing a JavaScript to add `id` to `input` tag, which don't work unfortunately.

Anyone successfully do it in Django without additional library? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `input` generated is only there to catch files, the actual data is either stored in hidden input fields (if you use `server` property) or encoded in those fields (if you use file encode plugin).

You can set `storeAsFile` to `true` to have FilePond update the fileList property of a file field. But that doesn't work on older versions of iOS, see link in property description:
https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/properties/